# get null for a file sent to a rest service with angular, how to send it properly?

Tags: angularjs, rest, file-upload

I'm new to programming,
I've tried to read post on the net and try a few thing but nothing get me to the point.
I try to have the option to upload a file on my webpage(exercice for study)
I've made  a rest service. When I make an html page with a regular form with input type file and submit button, it work fine. 
Also it redirect me to a page with a string from the response, but I want the string to be received as data to use in angular)
So i've made a page to upload with angular, and since, the best i can get in my directory is a file named null with ~17kb size.
So my question is how i can get with angular service with $http.post the same result as with a simple submit button ?
a page that load with ui-router:

```
    <h1>File Upload with Jersey</h1>

<form>

   <p>
    Select a file : <input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(file)"/>

   </p>

   <p>aaa{{file[0].name}}</p>


</form>
```

I use it with a controler as follow:

```
    (function()
{
var module = angular.module("couponAdmin");
module.controller("fileCtrl", fileCtrlCtor)

function fileCtrlCtor(uploadService,$scope) {

    $scope.uploadFile = function(item){
        uploadService.doPost(item);
    }

}

})();
```

and this is the service :

```
    (function(){var module = angular.module("couponAdmin");

module.service("uploadService", uploadServiceCtor);

function uploadServiceCtor($http,typeService,getterService) {

    this.doPost = function(item){
        this.fd = new FormData();
        this.fd.append("file", item);
        $http.post( "http://localhost:8080/couponService/webapi/file/upload",this.fd,{
                        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
                        transformRequest: angular.identity

                    }).then(
                function(promise){alert("success")
                },
                function(){
            alert("failure on uploaaaad")
            return;
        })
    }


}})()
```

here is the rest service:

```
 package marcwe.couponService;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericEntity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;


@Path("/file")
public class UploadFileService {

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

        String uploadedFileLocation = "d://uploaded/" + fileDetail.getFileName();

        // save it
        writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

        String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

        GenericEntity<String> entity = new GenericEntity<String>("uploaded"){};
        return Response.ok(entity,MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).status(Status.ACCEPTED).build();    

    }

    // save uploaded file to new location
    private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        String uploadedFileLocation) {

        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    uploadedFileLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```